# Setting up balanced payments with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, balanced-payments

I'm trying to start using balanced payments as a payment platform. I'm using rails so I did the gem install `gem "balanced"` but I know I have to also include the balanced.js to send credit card information. My question is does that gem automatically add balanced.js to the asset pipeline and then I simply reference it in the javascript/application.js `//= require balaced.js` ?

Or must I download balanced.js and include it in the asset pipeline?

Any sort of information would be great as I am new to using API's in rails thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the balanced gem is just a ruby wrapper that provides you with convenience methods for hitting their API so that you don't have to make raw HTTP requests.

If you don't want to download `balanced.js`, you can just include it in `app/views/layout/application.html.erb` as they recommend in their [documentation](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/#balanced-js):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.balancedpayments.com/v1/balanced.js"></script>
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjallday/BtXfr/), also from the documentation, contains a working demo with all the html and javascript needed for functional credit card tokenization.

Comment: Nice answer but add live url of balanced.js is get more time to get it so better way to download and add it.